# unhandled exception while opening OleDbConnection

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb

I am trying to read from excel and store data into database for web application but it gives error to OleDbConnection while opening.

It shows error:

> The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.

Please let me know if you have solution.Thanks in advance.

```
string path = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
                                 Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
OleDbConnection olcon=new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
try
{
    olcon.Open();
}
catch (NullReferenceException) { }
OleDbCommand cmd=new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]",olcon);
OleDbDataReader dr;
dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy=new SqlBulkCopy("Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial 
                                      Catalog=MvcDB;Integrated Security=True");
bulkcopy.DestinationTableName="EMPLOYEE";
bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);

olcon.Close();
```

Comment: either the excel is in read-only mode or it's not closed properly earlier when read using oledb connection

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have read/write permissions on the file with your user.
Second, make sure no one has a lock on the file.

Where is your file at ?
If it is a shared file on a network folder for example, you may have to close the file server-sided to remove the lock (or ask the person who opened the file to close it).

You may have to check where `FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName` is located.

Comment: file is not stored on server side.I already give full control to the file,but still its not working proprely.

Comment: Then there is some kind of lock to the file. Maybe your own program maintains a lock somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a file upload you need to map it to the server path.

```
string serverUploadArea = ...
var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(serverUploadArea + postedFile.FileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because this file is being used by FileUpload exclusively. To get rid of this you need to first save the file to a local directory or to a server path.

```
if (uploadOne.HasFile)
{
    string FileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadOne.PostedFile.FileName);
    string FolderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderPath"];
    string FilePath = FolderPath + FileName;
    ViewState["Name"] = FilePath; //Just if it needs to be used at later stage of time
    uploadOne.SaveAs(FilePath);
}
```

You can define the folder path in your connection string , i.e the directory if you want to save the file at a local directory.
If you don't want to save the file, I suggest you use EPPLUS library. It's available as a nuget package. Let me know of you would like me to share that one too.

Comment: I run this code but there is an error "The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path '~/Uploaded Folder/' is not rooted."

Comment: You need to give a local path like D:/FolderName/. Or you are just trying to save your file in the application folder itself. If later is the case then, try using Server.MapPath(FilePath)